# Is it possible to hide the server URL in dist (in Vue.js)?

Tags: vue.js, security, url

I have got a Vue.js project. When the development process is over, it will have to be distributed.
But how can I guarantee its safety?

The js files in "dist" folder contains the server URL like
`http://sample.org:8001/`
Suppose if a certain user changed all the URLs into his own URL, wouldn't it create a duplicate website?

If there is a way to ensure security, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Theft is something that is very hard to prevent in web-applications. As soon as you publish your application on the internet users will be able to run it (in there browser), therefore users will be able to copy the files you've published. In my experience though this rarely happens, it is not something I worry too much about.

Security-wise though, it's good that you are asking this question. It's very advisable to check your source code (and the dist-code) to ensure it does not contain any secrets: passwords, api keys, strategic business information, and such. There are even some tools that scan for this type of unintentional information leaks. I would advise you to research some more because this concern certainly isn't the only one.

Having a bundler and minifier/uglifier does not provide any security benefit, as these bundles are quite easy for a developer to take apart and/or reverse-engineer. Yes, use them for performance and convenience but don't think it will make the code more secure.